# What hash version is implemented on ThePirateBay.se? SHA-1 or MDA-5?

Tags: hash, torrent

I downloaded a File Checksum Utility executable file from Microsoft.
This tool is for checking the hash of a file.
I'm wondering what is the version of the "Info Hash" section on the torrent site "thepiratebay.se".
Is there anyone here knew what is it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SHA-1 is 160 bits (or 40 hexadecimal characters), whereas MD5 is only 128 bits (or 32 hexadecimal characters).

Using [this file](http://thepiratebay.se/torrent/10783627/Ubuntu_14.04_64-Bit_Minimal_Install_CD) as an example, the Info Hash is:

> 353E1F88B06C7AFBEB0692E25CE75F05A9E44FB0

Which is 40 hexadecimal characters, so I assume it's SHA-1.

Note that this value isn't the hash of the actual file you're trying to download, rather:

> These are hex encoded SHA-1 hash sums of the "info" sections of BitTorrent metafiles as used by BitTorrent to identify downloadable files or sets of files. For backwards compatibility with existing links, clients should also support the Base32 encoded version of the hash.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet_URI_scheme

I suspect you won't be able to use "File Checksum Utility" to verify this checksum, although your BitTorrent client probably has verification functionality built in.

For example in Transmission:

[image: Verify in Transmission]

Comment: Note that the BitTorrent protocol, by requirement, hashes all the incoming pieces and checks them against those stored in the `.torrent` file, so the integrity is guaranteed anyway.